# Unicode Character for New logo

Tags: css, unicode

Does anyone know if the unicode charset has anything like this:

[image: https://www.thevillageplayers.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/new_clipart-300x296.jpg]

Or somethin like this with Sale or Special ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the emoji  is in Unicode at U+1F195: SQUARED NEW. I don't see *Sale* or *Special*, but there are *Cool* () at U+1F192 and *Free* () at U+1F193.

Answer (score 1):

No, those don't exist in Unicode.

And they probably never will: it doesn't make sense to encode as Unicode characters logos that have strings in particular languages.

Comment: Actually, it is in Unicode. The emoji list includes several English words, and a few more Japanese words.
https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html#alphanum

Comment: Well, a square isn’t a many-pointed star. It’s not what was asked about. Yes, there are some emoji with words. Those were added into Unicode for compatibility with legacy Japanese cell phone systems. You won’t see more emoji like that added to Unicode.